# Is there anything I can do to fix this pygame_gui and FreeType2 error?

Tags: python, pygame-gui

I'm trying to make a GUI with `pygame_gui` and `pygame_gui` is throwing a error.

I made a simple GUI class like this:

```
import pygame
import pygame_gui

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((window.w, window.h))

    def init(self):
        self.hello_button = pygame_gui.elements.UIButton(relative_rect=pygame.Rect((0, 0), (100, 50)), text='UWU', manager=self.manager)

    def process_events(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame_gui.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED:
            if event.ui_element == self.hello_button:
                print("HI")
        self.manager.process_events(event)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.manager.update(dt)

    def render(self, window):
        self.manager.draw_ui(window)
```

If you look at the pygame_gui docs this is the same just put in a class.

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jacki\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python Projects\Uwu123\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    engine = Engine("C:\\Users\\jacki\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Coding\\Python Projects\\Uwu123\\assets")
  File "C:\Users\jacki\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python Projects\Uwu123\uwu123.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.gui = GUI(self)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python Projects\Uwu123\gui.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((engine.w, engine.h))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pygame_gui\ui_manager.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.ui_theme = UIAppearanceTheme(self.resource_loader, self._locale)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pygame_gui\core\ui_appearance_theme.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.font_dict = UIFontDictionary(self._resource_loader, locale)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pygame_gui\core\ui_font_dictionary.py", line 128, in __init__
    self._load_default_font()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pygame_gui\core\ui_font_dictionary.py", line 156, in _load_default_font
    error = default_font_res.load()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pygame_gui\core\utility.py", line 395, in load
    self.loaded_font = GUIFontFreetype(
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pygame_gui\core\gui_font_freetype.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.__internal_font: Font = Font(file, size, resolution=72)
RuntimeError: The FreeType 2 library hasn't been initialized
```

I tried to install `FreeType2`, but it didn't work because I couldn't find build instructions.

Comment: Die you call `pygame.init`/`pygame.display.set_mode`?

Comment: I called both of those functions before I initialize the GUI and I get the same error.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error with the snippet provided, please give minimal reproducible example...

Comment: To check whether you really initialized pygame before GUI initialization, locate this line ``File "C:\Users\jacki\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python Projects\Uwu123\main.py", line 5`` and just before it add a line ``print(pygame.get_init(), pygame.freetype.get_init())``. If everything works correctly you should see ``True True`` in the console.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found my issue my IDE (Pycharm) got mad at me and thought that pygame.freetype did not exist. So that's why I posted this question.